# Remove Elements from one Queue that are present in another queue

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Using C#

I have

Queue N: 3, 4 9, 11

Queue A: 1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13

I want to remove all elements from Queue A that are present in Queue N

And end up with Queue R: 1, 2, 8, 12, 13

How do I do this in C#

Trying to work with someones API and they offer a way to get the two queues and I need to filter based on one queue returned.

Thanks,

-Seth

Updated Code Example:

I am using a custom data type ModuleDetails

```
Queue<ModuleDetails> defaultQueue = apiCallDefault();
Queue<ModuleDetails> modQueue = apiCallAllModules();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easiest to do it with LINQ-to-Objects...

```
var qN = new Queue<int>(new[]{3, 4, 9, 11});
var qA = new Queue<int>(new[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13});
var qR = qA.Except(qN);
```

UPDATE: As long as ModuleDetails implements IEquatable, the code below will work just fine. If you can't modify ModuleDetails, you can always supply an IEqualityComparer as the second argument of Except, which defines how equality is determined.

Comment: Then call `new Queue<int>(qR);` to make it a `Queue<T>` and not an `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Is there something different than Linq?

Comment: @Seth: "Linq-to-Objects" means using normal Linq on normal (`IEnumerable<T>`) objects.  This is opposed to Linq-to-Entities or something, which uses a provider to translate Linq statements into SQL, rather than executing them directly.

Comment: @Seth - If you are using .NET 3.5 or 4.0, the above code works just fine. If not, you can foreach over qA and add the item to a qR if it is not contained in qN.

Comment: This is a .Net 2.0 Project so that would be why it was having trouble accomplishing this with the Linq to objects solution.

Answer (score 1):

It's important to note that if your queue was filled with your custom objects, then you would have to implement IEqualityComparer interface. Obviously you won't need it for the int type since it already implements the interface.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use linq, look at Except method.

```
int[] first  = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
int[] second = new int[] {             4, 5, 6,         10 };

var q = first.Except(second);
```